# Symfony 5: Get id user

Tags: php, symfony

when a user logs in my app with email and pass, redirects to url like profile/{id} . It is necessary to pass the user id in the redirectResponse, but I don't know how to capture it...

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{

    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
    //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('profile_id'));
}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-fetching-the-user-object

Comment: The problem it's i don't know how to capture the user in this step... when the user logs in the app with his email and password...

Comment: $token->getUser()->getId() should do the trick.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "capture"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to your current user with `$token->getUser()`.

For exemple if your route name is `user_profile`, you can do something like this :

```php
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{

    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate(
        'user_profile',
        ['id' => $token->getUser()->getId()]
    ));
}
```

Comment: This is a valid technical solution but since the user is connected, I guess the behavior should rather make the route match on /profile and then get the current user in the controller. Somethng like $this->getUser() (if you extends the AbstractController)

Comment: yes you are totally right, it's good to specify it, but it can be useful for other situations that we can access user from TokenInterface after login success.